# Likerts' scale usability in Google Forms

Tags: usability, cognitive-load

I've stumbled upon the way Google Forms uses Likert scale for mobile devices. Is there any reason why **horizontal axis** isn't fixed when user is scrolling down the Likert scale?
Looking from UX point of view I'd say that fixing the horizontal axis (making it visible at all time when user scrolls) would minimize the cognitive load and increase the usability. Is there any reasons why Google chose this way? Reference image is down below.

[image]